# Настройка ide SASM на Windows 10

Tags: ассемблер, sasm

Периодически интересуюсь ассемблером под всякие UNIX OC (Ubuntu), которые запускаю в качестве виртуальной машины на VirtualBox. Но, для меня, это оказалось не очень удобно - сам я сижу на Windows 10.
От чего решил пересесть на SASM, но там оказался компоновщик GCC (я думаю проблема в нём). Который пихает в код 32bit-ного NASM-а, всякие высокоуровневые Сишные функции (PRINT_STRING msg и NEWLINE) из файла %include "io.inc". И начинает ругаться если писать без этого. Собственно, как исправить и вернуть старую добрую простоту синтаксиса ?

```
%include "io.inc"

section .data
    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0

section .text
    global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp
    PRINT_STRING msg
    NEWLINE
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

P.s: думал впихнуть компоновщик встроенный в систему Linux и ему подобные, но оказалась не так то просто ...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116667/discussion-on-question-by-user409986--ide-sasm--windows-10).

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически SASM можно настроить, чтобы в результате компиляции получался исполняемый файл для Linux, но такой исполняемый файл не будет работать из Windows, только из виртуальной машины с установленной ОС Linux.

Никакой эмуляции в SASM нет, поэтому код с системными вызовами Linux под Windows работать не будет.

Для ввода-вывода используются макросы, которые обращаются к функциям библиотеки [libc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8), которые по-разному реализованы в разных ОС (например, под Linux берется GLIBC, под Windows - Microsoft Visual C Runtime (msvcrt)), собирается все в формат исполняемого файла, нативного для каждой системы, таким образом получается некая кроссплатформенность.